# Rolling back jQuery 3 makes MVC client side validation fail?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC app with Bootstrap 3. I added MVC client side validation to my form and it was working correctly. If there were errors it would display the error message and prevent the postback. This was using the jQuery 1.10.2 that comes with the standard VS2015 MVC template.

I then saw the suggested updated in NuGet to go to jQuery 3 and foolishly I decided to let it upgrade. That caused JS errors and made it so that my Bootstap menu would work not any of the client validation.

So, I rolled back to jQuery 1.10.2 which wasn't easy. However, now my MVC client validation doesn't work. It allows the form to do a postback. I can't figure out what all needs to be done to get to work again.

Here is what I checked:

Web.config

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

One of my ViewModel properties

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "*Required")]
public string Sequence { get; set; }
```

View

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <label class="control-label">Sequence</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Sequence, new { @maxlength = "6", @class = "form-control", autofocus = "autofocus" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Sequence, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

Bottom of my _Layout.cshtml

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

BundleConfig.cs

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
            "~/Scripts/DigitalBrushMaskedInput.min_1.4.1.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem and wanted to post it in case someone else comes across it.

Basically I was missing the jquery.validate.js file in my Scripts folder. I was having another JS error dealing with jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js and it led me to figure out that I was missing the validate file which must have been removed when I rolled back the jQuery.

One thing I did was created a new simple MVC site. I then compared the files in the Scripts folder with what I had in my other project's scripts folder.

Hope this helps someone else down the road.